# SQL replace incomplete days of the week in the month to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
   date     week_day
1-02-2018      4
2-02-2018      5
3-02-2018      6
4-02-2018      7
5-02-2018      1
6-02-2018      2
7-02-2018      3
................
26-02-2018     1
27-02-2018     2
28-02-2018     3
```

I need to get in SQL incomplete weeks to next in the following form:

```
   date     week_day
0              1
0              2
0              3
1-02-2018      4
2-02-2018      5
3-02-2018      6
4-02-2018      7
5-02-2018      1
6-02-2018      2
7-02-2018      3
................
26-02-2018     1
27-02-2018     2
28-02-2018     3 
0              4
0              5
0              6 
0              7
```

Comment: put date and week in 2D array, itirate througth each one with foreach and make changes when week day is missing.

Comment: I need to do it on sql ^_^

Comment: Are just the days in February 2018 in the table?

Comment: So in other words, the ragged ends of the whole weeks which fall at each end of the month should have a date of `0`? There are several ways you could approach this, but what I'd probably suggest is to boil down the table of dates you have into a min iso week number, max iso week number, and a month number, then filter the rows of an (appropriately designed) date table according to week number (so that you get the portion of the weeks whose dates fall outside the month), then zero out the joined dates which don't fall inside the month.

Comment: So you need it always start with 1 and end with 7?

Comment: @Sami Yes, from 1 (Monday) to 7(Sunday)

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison No ,in the table can be several months and for each month it is necessary to add incomplete weeks of NULL values

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for:

```
DECLARE @FirstDate date =
(
    SELECT MIN(DATEADD(DAY, (week_day - 1) * -1, [date]))
    FROM YourTable
)

DECLARE @LastDate date =
(
    SELECT MAX(DATEADD(DAY, 7 - week_day, [date]))
    FROM YourTable
)
;

WITH cteDates
AS
(
    SELECT
        @FirstDate [date]
        , 1 week_day

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, [date])
        , CASE WHEN week_day + 1 > 7 THEN 1 ELSE week_day + 1 END
    FROM cteDates
    WHERE [date] < @LastDate
)

SELECT
    T.[date]
    , C.week_day
FROM
    cteDates C
    LEFT JOIN YourTable T ON
        C.[date] = T.[date]
        AND C.week_day = T.week_day
```

Answer (score 0):

The main key is to get the cartesian join of the (year, month, week) and weekdays then do a left join on the dates in question. The second key is to adjust for Monday being to the start of the week.

Here is an example that works in MySQL. It has one edge case which I have not yet resolved. The case of a month's last day ending on a Sunday. In that case, there are 7 zeros between the end of that month and the start of the next.

```
select * from (
    select cartesian.`year`
    , cartesian.`month`
    , cartesian.`week`  
    , coalesce(dates.`date`,0) `date`, cartesian.weekday+1 week_day from (
        /* get distinct cartesian results for the (year, month, week) and weekday */
        select `year`
        , `month`
        , case weekday when 6 then `week` - 1 else `week` end `week`
        , weekday
        from (
            select distinct year(`date`) `year`
            , month(`date`) `month`
            , week(`date`) `week`
            , weeks.weekday
            from date_48361641, (
                select 0 weekday union
                select 1 weekday union
                select 2 weekday union
                select 3 weekday union
                select 4 weekday union
                select 5 weekday union
                select 6 weekday
            ) weeks
        ) weeks
        -- order by `year`, `month`, `week`, `weekday`
    ) cartesian
    left join (
        /* adjust for edge case of week 0 */
        select `date`
            , `year`
            , `month`
            , `week` 
            , weekday
        from (
            /* adjust the week to allow for Monday start of week*/
            select `date`
                , `year`
                , `month`
                , case weekday when 6 then `week` - 1 else `week` end `week`
                , weekday
                from (
                select `date`
                , year(`date`) `year`
                , month(`date`) `month`
                , week(`date`) `week`
                , weekday(`date`) weekday
                from date_48361641 dates
                -- order by `date`  
            ) dates
        ) dates
    ) dates
    on dates.`year` = cartesian.`year`
    and dates.`month` = cartesian.`month`
    and dates.`week` = cartesian.`week`
    and dates.`weekday` = cartesian.`weekday`
) results
where results.`week` > -1 
order by 
results.`year`
, results.`month`
, results.`week`
, results.`week_day`
```

--  results

```
year    month   week    date    week_day
2016    1   0   0   1
2016    1   0   0   2
2016    1   0   0   3
2016    1   0   0   4
2016    1   0   2016-01-01  5
2016    1   0   2016-01-02  6
2016    1   0   2016-01-03  7
...
2016    1   4   2016-01-25  1
2016    1   4   2016-01-26  2
2016    1   4   2016-01-27  3
2016    1   4   2016-01-28  4
2016    1   4   2016-01-29  5
2016    1   4   2016-01-30  6
2016    1   4   2016-01-31  7
2016    1   5   0   1
2016    1   5   0   2
2016    1   5   0   3
2016    1   5   0   4
2016    1   5   0   5
2016    1   5   0   6
2016    2   4   0   7
2016    2   5   2016-02-01  1
2016    2   5   2016-02-02  2
2016    2   5   2016-02-03  3
2016    2   5   2016-02-04  4
2016    2   5   2016-02-05  5
2016    2   5   2016-02-06  6
2016    2   5   2016-02-07  7
...
2016    2   9   2016-02-29  1
2016    2   9   0   2
2016    2   9   0   3
2016    2   9   0   4
2016    2   9   0   5
2016    2   9   0   6
2016    3   8   0   7
2016    3   9   0   1
2016    3   9   2016-03-01  2
2016    3   9   2016-03-02  3
2016    3   9   2016-03-03  4
2016    3   9   2016-03-04  5
2016    3   9   2016-03-05  6
2016    3   9   2016-03-06  7
...
2016    3   13  2016-03-28  1
2016    3   13  2016-03-29  2
2016    3   13  2016-03-30  3
2016    3   13  2016-03-31  4
2016    3   13  0   5
2016    3   13  0   6
2016    4   12  0   7
2016    4   13  0   1
2016    4   13  0   2
2016    4   13  0   3
2016    4   13  0   4
2016    4   13  2016-04-01  5
2016    4   13  2016-04-02  6
2016    4   13  2016-04-03  7
...
2016    5   22  2016-05-30  1
2016    5   22  2016-05-31  2
2016    5   22  0   3
2016    5   22  0   4
2016    5   22  0   5
2016    5   22  0   6
2016    6   21  0   7
2016    6   22  0   1
2016    6   22  0   2
2016    6   22  2016-06-01  3
2016    6   22  2016-06-02  4
2016    6   22  2016-06-03  5
2016    6   22  2016-06-04  6
2016    6   22  2016-06-05  7
...
2016    6   26  2016-06-27  1
2016    6   26  2016-06-28  2
2016    6   26  2016-06-29  3
2016    6   26  2016-06-30  4
2016    6   26  0   5
2016    6   26  0   6
2016    7   25  0   7
2016    7   26  0   1
2016    7   26  0   2
2016    7   26  0   3
2016    7   26  0   4
2016    7   26  2016-07-01  5
2016    7   26  2016-07-02  6
2016    7   26  2016-07-03  7
...
2016    7   30  2016-07-25  1
2016    7   30  2016-07-26  2
2016    7   30  2016-07-27  3
2016    7   30  2016-07-28  4
2016    7   30  2016-07-29  5
2016    7   30  2016-07-30  6
2016    7   30  2016-07-31  7
2016    7   31  0   1
2016    7   31  0   2
2016    7   31  0   3
2016    7   31  0   4
2016    7   31  0   5
2016    7   31  0   6
2016    8   30  0   7
2016    8   31  2016-08-01  1
2016    8   31  2016-08-02  2
2016    8   31  2016-08-03  3
2016    8   31  2016-08-04  4
2016    8   31  2016-08-05  5
2016    8   31  2016-08-06  6
2016    8   31  2016-08-07  7
...
2016    8   35  2016-08-29  1
2016    8   35  2016-08-30  2
2016    8   35  2016-08-31  3
2016    8   35  0   4
2016    8   35  0   5
2016    8   35  0   6
2016    9   34  0   7
2016    9   35  0   1
2016    9   35  0   2
2016    9   35  0   3
2016    9   35  2016-09-01  4
2016    9   35  2016-09-02  5
2016    9   35  2016-09-03  6
2016    9   35  2016-09-04  7
...
2016    9   39  2016-09-26  1
2016    9   39  2016-09-27  2
2016    9   39  2016-09-28  3
2016    9   39  2016-09-29  4
2016    9   39  2016-09-30  5
2016    9   39  0   6
2016    10  38  0   7
2016    10  39  0   1
2016    10  39  0   2
2016    10  39  0   3
2016    10  39  0   4
2016    10  39  0   5
2016    10  39  2016-10-01  6
2016    10  39  2016-10-02  7
...
2016    10  44  2016-10-31  1
2016    10  44  0   2
2016    10  44  0   3
2016    10  44  0   4
2016    10  44  0   5
2016    10  44  0   6
2016    11  43  0   7
2016    11  44  0   1
2016    11  44  2016-11-01  2
2016    11  44  2016-11-02  3
2016    11  44  2016-11-03  4
2016    11  44  2016-11-04  5
2016    11  44  2016-11-05  6
2016    11  44  2016-11-06  7
...
2016    11  48  2016-11-28  1
2016    11  48  2016-11-29  2
2016    11  48  2016-11-30  3
2016    11  48  0   4
2016    11  48  0   5
2016    11  48  0   6
2016    12  47  0   7
2016    12  48  0   1
2016    12  48  0   2
2016    12  48  0   3
2016    12  48  2016-12-01  4
2016    12  48  2016-12-02  5
2016    12  48  2016-12-03  6
2016    12  48  2016-12-04  7
2016    12  49  2016-12-05  1
2016    12  49  2016-12-06  2
2016    12  49  2016-12-07  3
2016    12  49  2016-12-08  4
2016    12  49  2016-12-09  5
2016    12  49  2016-12-10  6
2016    12  49  2016-12-11  7
2016    12  50  2016-12-12  1
2016    12  50  2016-12-13  2
2016    12  50  2016-12-14  3
2016    12  50  2016-12-15  4
2016    12  50  2016-12-16  5
2016    12  50  2016-12-17  6
2016    12  50  2016-12-18  7
2016    12  51  2016-12-19  1
2016    12  51  2016-12-20  2
2016    12  51  2016-12-21  3
2016    12  51  2016-12-22  4
2016    12  51  2016-12-23  5
2016    12  51  2016-12-24  6
2016    12  51  2016-12-25  7
2016    12  52  2016-12-26  1
2016    12  52  2016-12-27  2
2016    12  52  2016-12-28  3
2016    12  52  2016-12-29  4
2016    12  52  2016-12-30  5
2016    12  52  2016-12-31  6
2017    1   0   2017-01-01  7
2017    1   1   2017-01-02  1
2017    1   1   2017-01-03  2
2017    1   1   2017-01-04  3
2017    1   1   2017-01-05  4
2017    1   1   2017-01-06  5
2017    1   1   2017-01-07  6
2017    1   1   2017-01-08  7
2017    1   2   2017-01-09  1
2017    1   2   2017-01-10  2
2017    1   2   2017-01-11  3
2017    1   2   2017-01-12  4
2017    1   2   2017-01-13  5
2017    1   2   2017-01-14  6
2017    1   2   2017-01-15  7
2017    1   3   2017-01-16  1
2017    1   3   2017-01-17  2
2017    1   3   2017-01-18  3
2017    1   3   2017-01-19  4
2017    1   3   2017-01-20  5
2017    1   3   2017-01-21  6
2017    1   3   2017-01-22  7
2017    1   4   2017-01-23  1
2017    1   4   2017-01-24  2
2017    1   4   2017-01-25  3
2017    1   4   2017-01-26  4
2017    1   4   2017-01-27  5
2017    1   4   2017-01-28  6
2017    1   4   2017-01-29  7
2017    1   5   2017-01-30  1
2017    1   5   2017-01-31  2
2017    1   5   0   3
2017    1   5   0   4
2017    1   5   0   5
2017    1   5   0   6
2017    2   4   0   7
2017    2   5   0   1
2017    2   5   0   2
2017    2   5   2017-02-01  3
2017    2   5   2017-02-02  4
2017    2   5   2017-02-03  5
2017    2   5   2017-02-04  6
2017    2   5   2017-02-05  7
2017    2   6   2017-02-06  1
2017    2   6   2017-02-07  2
2017    2   6   2017-02-08  3
2017    2   6   2017-02-09  4
2017    2   6   2017-02-10  5
2017    2   6   2017-02-11  6
2017    2   6   2017-02-12  7
2017    2   7   2017-02-13  1
2017    2   7   2017-02-14  2
2017    2   7   2017-02-15  3
2017    2   7   2017-02-16  4
2017    2   7   2017-02-17  5
2017    2   7   2017-02-18  6
2017    2   7   2017-02-19  7
2017    2   8   2017-02-20  1
2017    2   8   2017-02-21  2
2017    2   8   2017-02-22  3
2017    2   8   2017-02-23  4
2017    2   8   2017-02-24  5
2017    2   8   2017-02-25  6
2017    2   8   2017-02-26  7
2017    2   9   2017-02-27  1
2017    2   9   2017-02-28  2
2017    2   9   0   3
2017    2   9   0   4
2017    2   9   0   5
2017    2   9   0   6
2017    3   8   0   7
2017    3   9   0   1
2017    3   9   0   2
2017    3   9   2017-03-01  3
2017    3   9   2017-03-02  4
2017    3   9   2017-03-03  5
2017    3   9   2017-03-04  6
2017    3   9   2017-03-05  7
2017    3   10  2017-03-06  1
2017    3   10  2017-03-07  2
2017    3   10  2017-03-08  3
2017    3   10  2017-03-09  4
2017    3   10  2017-03-10  5
2017    3   10  2017-03-11  6
2017    3   10  2017-03-12  7
2017    3   11  2017-03-13  1
2017    3   11  2017-03-14  2
2017    3   11  2017-03-15  3
2017    3   11  2017-03-16  4
2017    3   11  2017-03-17  5
2017    3   11  2017-03-18  6
2017    3   11  2017-03-19  7
2017    3   12  2017-03-20  1
2017    3   12  2017-03-21  2
2017    3   12  2017-03-22  3
2017    3   12  2017-03-23  4
2017    3   12  2017-03-24  5
2017    3   12  2017-03-25  6
2017    3   12  2017-03-26  7
2017    3   13  2017-03-27  1
2017    3   13  2017-03-28  2
2017    3   13  2017-03-29  3
2017    3   13  2017-03-30  4
2017    3   13  2017-03-31  5
2017    3   13  0   6
2017    4   12  0   7
2017    4   13  0   1
2017    4   13  0   2
2017    4   13  0   3
2017    4   13  0   4
2017    4   13  0   5
2017    4   13  2017-04-01  6
2017    4   13  2017-04-02  7
2017    4   14  2017-04-03  1
2017    4   14  2017-04-04  2
2017    4   14  2017-04-05  3
2017    4   14  2017-04-06  4
2017    4   14  2017-04-07  5
2017    4   14  2017-04-08  6
2017    4   14  2017-04-09  7
2017    4   15  2017-04-10  1
2017    4   15  2017-04-11  2
2017    4   15  2017-04-12  3
2017    4   15  2017-04-13  4
2017    4   15  2017-04-14  5
2017    4   15  2017-04-15  6
2017    4   15  2017-04-16  7
2017    4   16  2017-04-17  1
2017    4   16  2017-04-18  2
2017    4   16  2017-04-19  3
2017    4   16  2017-04-20  4
2017    4   16  2017-04-21  5
2017    4   16  2017-04-22  6
2017    4   16  2017-04-23  7
2017    4   17  2017-04-24  1
2017    4   17  2017-04-25  2
2017    4   17  2017-04-26  3
2017    4   17  2017-04-27  4
2017    4   17  2017-04-28  5
2017    4   17  2017-04-29  6
2017    4   17  2017-04-30  7
2017    4   18  0   1
2017    4   18  0   2
2017    4   18  0   3
2017    4   18  0   4
2017    4   18  0   5
2017    4   18  0   6
2017    5   17  0   7
2017    5   18  2017-05-01  1
2017    5   18  2017-05-02  2
2017    5   18  2017-05-03  3
2017    5   18  2017-05-04  4
2017    5   18  2017-05-05  5
2017    5   18  2017-05-06  6
2017    5   18  2017-05-07  7
2017    5   19  2017-05-08  1
2017    5   19  2017-05-09  2
2017    5   19  2017-05-10  3
2017    5   19  2017-05-11  4
2017    5   19  2017-05-12  5
2017    5   19  2017-05-13  6
2017    5   19  2017-05-14  7
2017    5   20  2017-05-15  1
2017    5   20  2017-05-16  2
2017    5   20  2017-05-17  3
2017    5   20  2017-05-18  4
2017    5   20  2017-05-19  5
2017    5   20  2017-05-20  6
2017    5   20  2017-05-21  7
2017    5   21  2017-05-22  1
2017    5   21  2017-05-23  2
2017    5   21  2017-05-24  3
2017    5   21  2017-05-25  4
2017    5   21  2017-05-26  5
2017    5   21  2017-05-27  6
2017    5   21  2017-05-28  7
2017    5   22  2017-05-29  1
2017    5   22  2017-05-30  2
2017    5   22  2017-05-31  3
2017    5   22  0   4
2017    5   22  0   5
2017    5   22  0   6
2017    6   21  0   7
2017    6   22  0   1
2017    6   22  0   2
2017    6   22  0   3
2017    6   22  2017-06-01  4
2017    6   22  2017-06-02  5
2017    6   22  2017-06-03  6
2017    6   22  2017-06-04  7
2017    6   23  2017-06-05  1
2017    6   23  2017-06-06  2
2017    6   23  2017-06-07  3
2017    6   23  2017-06-08  4
2017    6   23  2017-06-09  5
2017    6   23  2017-06-10  6
2017    6   23  2017-06-11  7
2017    6   24  2017-06-12  1
2017    6   24  2017-06-13  2
2017    6   24  2017-06-14  3
2017    6   24  2017-06-15  4
2017    6   24  2017-06-16  5
2017    6   24  2017-06-17  6
2017    6   24  2017-06-18  7
2017    6   25  2017-06-19  1
2017    6   25  2017-06-20  2
2017    6   25  2017-06-21  3
2017    6   25  2017-06-22  4
2017    6   25  2017-06-23  5
2017    6   25  2017-06-24  6
2017    6   25  2017-06-25  7
2017    6   26  2017-06-26  1
2017    6   26  2017-06-27  2
2017    6   26  2017-06-28  3
2017    6   26  2017-06-29  4
2017    6   26  2017-06-30  5
2017    6   26  0   6
2017    7   25  0   7
2017    7   26  0   1
2017    7   26  0   2
2017    7   26  0   3
2017    7   26  0   4
2017    7   26  0   5
2017    7   26  2017-07-01  6
2017    7   26  2017-07-02  7
2017    7   27  2017-07-03  1
2017    7   27  2017-07-04  2
2017    7   27  2017-07-05  3
2017    7   27  2017-07-06  4
2017    7   27  2017-07-07  5
2017    7   27  2017-07-08  6
2017    7   27  2017-07-09  7
2017    7   28  2017-07-10  1
2017    7   28  2017-07-11  2
2017    7   28  2017-07-12  3
2017    7   28  2017-07-13  4
2017    7   28  2017-07-14  5
2017    7   28  2017-07-15  6
2017    7   28  2017-07-16  7
2017    7   29  2017-07-17  1
2017    7   29  2017-07-18  2
2017    7   29  2017-07-19  3
2017    7   29  2017-07-20  4
2017    7   29  2017-07-21  5
2017    7   29  2017-07-22  6
2017    7   29  2017-07-23  7
2017    7   30  2017-07-24  1
2017    7   30  2017-07-25  2
2017    7   30  2017-07-26  3
2017    7   30  2017-07-27  4
2017    7   30  2017-07-28  5
2017    7   30  2017-07-29  6
2017    7   30  2017-07-30  7
2017    7   31  2017-07-31  1
2017    7   31  0   2
2017    7   31  0   3
2017    7   31  0   4
2017    7   31  0   5
2017    7   31  0   6
2017    8   30  0   7
2017    8   31  0   1
2017    8   31  2017-08-01  2
2017    8   31  2017-08-02  3
2017    8   31  2017-08-03  4
2017    8   31  2017-08-04  5
2017    8   31  2017-08-05  6
2017    8   31  2017-08-06  7
2017    8   32  2017-08-07  1
2017    8   32  2017-08-08  2
2017    8   32  2017-08-09  3
2017    8   32  2017-08-10  4
2017    8   32  2017-08-11  5
2017    8   32  2017-08-12  6
2017    8   32  2017-08-13  7
2017    8   33  2017-08-14  1
2017    8   33  2017-08-15  2
2017    8   33  2017-08-16  3
2017    8   33  2017-08-17  4
2017    8   33  2017-08-18  5
2017    8   33  2017-08-19  6
2017    8   33  2017-08-20  7
2017    8   34  2017-08-21  1
2017    8   34  2017-08-22  2
2017    8   34  2017-08-23  3
2017    8   34  2017-08-24  4
2017    8   34  2017-08-25  5
2017    8   34  2017-08-26  6
2017    8   34  2017-08-27  7
2017    8   35  2017-08-28  1
2017    8   35  2017-08-29  2
2017    8   35  2017-08-30  3
2017    8   35  2017-08-31  4
2017    8   35  0   5
2017    8   35  0   6
2017    9   34  0   7
2017    9   35  0   1
2017    9   35  0   2
2017    9   35  0   3
2017    9   35  0   4
2017    9   35  2017-09-01  5
2017    9   35  2017-09-02  6
2017    9   35  2017-09-03  7
2017    9   36  2017-09-04  1
2017    9   36  2017-09-05  2
2017    9   36  2017-09-06  3
2017    9   36  2017-09-07  4
2017    9   36  2017-09-08  5
2017    9   36  2017-09-09  6
2017    9   36  2017-09-10  7
2017    9   37  2017-09-11  1
2017    9   37  2017-09-12  2
2017    9   37  2017-09-13  3
2017    9   37  2017-09-14  4
2017    9   37  2017-09-15  5
2017    9   37  2017-09-16  6
2017    9   37  2017-09-17  7
2017    9   38  2017-09-18  1
2017    9   38  2017-09-19  2
2017    9   38  2017-09-20  3
2017    9   38  2017-09-21  4
2017    9   38  2017-09-22  5
2017    9   38  2017-09-23  6
2017    9   38  2017-09-24  7
2017    9   39  2017-09-25  1
2017    9   39  2017-09-26  2
2017    9   39  2017-09-27  3
2017    9   39  2017-09-28  4
2017    9   39  2017-09-29  5
2017    9   39  2017-09-30  6
2017    10  39  2017-10-01  7
2017    10  40  2017-10-02  1
2017    10  40  2017-10-03  2
2017    10  40  2017-10-04  3
2017    10  40  2017-10-05  4
2017    10  40  2017-10-06  5
2017    10  40  2017-10-07  6
2017    10  40  2017-10-08  7
2017    10  41  2017-10-09  1
2017    10  41  2017-10-10  2
2017    10  41  2017-10-11  3
2017    10  41  2017-10-12  4
2017    10  41  2017-10-13  5
2017    10  41  2017-10-14  6
2017    10  41  2017-10-15  7
2017    10  42  2017-10-16  1
2017    10  42  2017-10-17  2
2017    10  42  2017-10-18  3
2017    10  42  2017-10-19  4
2017    10  42  2017-10-20  5
2017    10  42  2017-10-21  6
2017    10  42  2017-10-22  7
2017    10  43  2017-10-23  1
2017    10  43  2017-10-24  2
2017    10  43  2017-10-25  3
2017    10  43  2017-10-26  4
2017    10  43  2017-10-27  5
2017    10  43  2017-10-28  6
2017    10  43  2017-10-29  7
2017    10  44  2017-10-30  1
2017    10  44  2017-10-31  2
2017    10  44  0   3
2017    10  44  0   4
2017    10  44  0   5
2017    10  44  0   6
2017    11  43  0   7
2017    11  44  0   1
2017    11  44  0   2
2017    11  44  2017-11-01  3
2017    11  44  2017-11-02  4
2017    11  44  2017-11-03  5
2017    11  44  2017-11-04  6
2017    11  44  2017-11-05  7
2017    11  45  2017-11-06  1
2017    11  45  2017-11-07  2
2017    11  45  2017-11-08  3
2017    11  45  2017-11-09  4
2017    11  45  2017-11-10  5
2017    11  45  2017-11-11  6
2017    11  45  2017-11-12  7
2017    11  46  2017-11-13  1
2017    11  46  2017-11-14  2
2017    11  46  2017-11-15  3
2017    11  46  2017-11-16  4
2017    11  46  2017-11-17  5
2017    11  46  2017-11-18  6
2017    11  46  2017-11-19  7
2017    11  47  2017-11-20  1
2017    11  47  2017-11-21  2
2017    11  47  2017-11-22  3
2017    11  47  2017-11-23  4
2017    11  47  2017-11-24  5
2017    11  47  2017-11-25  6
2017    11  47  2017-11-26  7
2017    11  48  2017-11-27  1
2017    11  48  2017-11-28  2
2017    11  48  2017-11-29  3
2017    11  48  2017-11-30  4
2017    11  48  0   5
2017    11  48  0   6
2017    12  47  0   7
2017    12  48  0   1
2017    12  48  0   2
2017    12  48  0   3
2017    12  48  0   4
2017    12  48  2017-12-01  5
2017    12  48  2017-12-02  6
2017    12  48  2017-12-03  7
2017    12  49  2017-12-04  1
2017    12  49  2017-12-05  2
2017    12  49  2017-12-06  3
2017    12  49  2017-12-07  4
2017    12  49  2017-12-08  5
2017    12  49  2017-12-09  6
2017    12  49  2017-12-10  7
2017    12  50  2017-12-11  1
2017    12  50  2017-12-12  2
2017    12  50  2017-12-13  3
2017    12  50  2017-12-14  4
2017    12  50  2017-12-15  5
2017    12  50  2017-12-16  6
2017    12  50  2017-12-17  7
2017    12  51  2017-12-18  1
2017    12  51  2017-12-19  2
2017    12  51  2017-12-20  3
2017    12  51  2017-12-21  4
2017    12  51  2017-12-22  5
2017    12  51  2017-12-23  6
2017    12  51  2017-12-24  7
2017    12  52  2017-12-25  1
2017    12  52  2017-12-26  2
2017    12  52  2017-12-27  3
2017    12  52  2017-12-28  4
2017    12  52  2017-12-29  5
2017    12  52  2017-12-30  6
2017    12  52  2017-12-31  7
2017    12  53  0   1
2017    12  53  0   2
2017    12  53  0   3
2017    12  53  0   4
2017    12  53  0   5
2017    12  53  0   6
2018    1   0   2018-01-01  1
2018    1   0   2018-01-02  2
2018    1   0   2018-01-03  3
2018    1   0   2018-01-04  4
2018    1   0   2018-01-05  5
2018    1   0   2018-01-06  6
2018    1   0   2018-01-07  7
2018    1   1   2018-01-08  1
2018    1   1   2018-01-09  2
2018    1   1   2018-01-10  3
2018    1   1   2018-01-11  4
2018    1   1   2018-01-12  5
2018    1   1   2018-01-13  6
2018    1   1   2018-01-14  7
2018    1   2   2018-01-15  1
2018    1   2   2018-01-16  2
2018    1   2   2018-01-17  3
2018    1   2   2018-01-18  4
2018    1   2   2018-01-19  5
2018    1   2   2018-01-20  6
2018    1   2   2018-01-21  7
2018    1   3   2018-01-22  1
2018    1   3   2018-01-23  2
2018    1   3   2018-01-24  3
2018    1   3   2018-01-25  4
2018    1   3   2018-01-26  5
2018    1   3   2018-01-27  6
2018    1   3   2018-01-28  7
2018    1   4   2018-01-29  1
2018    1   4   2018-01-30  2
2018    1   4   2018-01-31  3
2018    1   4   0   4
2018    1   4   0   5
2018    1   4   0   6
2018    2   3   0   7
2018    2   4   0   1
2018    2   4   0   2
2018    2   4   0   3
2018    2   4   2018-02-01  4
2018    2   4   2018-02-02  5
2018    2   4   2018-02-03  6
2018    2   4   2018-02-04  7
2018    2   5   2018-02-05  1
2018    2   5   2018-02-06  2
2018    2   5   2018-02-07  3
2018    2   5   2018-02-08  4
2018    2   5   2018-02-09  5
2018    2   5   2018-02-10  6
2018    2   5   2018-02-11  7
2018    2   6   2018-02-12  1
2018    2   6   2018-02-13  2
2018    2   6   2018-02-14  3
2018    2   6   2018-02-15  4
2018    2   6   2018-02-16  5
2018    2   6   2018-02-17  6
2018    2   6   2018-02-18  7
2018    2   7   2018-02-19  1
2018    2   7   2018-02-20  2
2018    2   7   2018-02-21  3
2018    2   7   2018-02-22  4
2018    2   7   2018-02-23  5
2018    2   7   2018-02-24  6
2018    2   7   2018-02-25  7
2018    2   8   2018-02-26  1
2018    2   8   2018-02-27  2
2018    2   8   2018-02-28  3
2018    2   8   0   4
2018    2   8   0   5
2018    2   8   0   6
2018    3   7   0   7
2018    3   8   0   1
2018    3   8   0   2
2018    3   8   0   3
2018    3   8   2018-03-01  4
2018    3   8   2018-03-02  5
2018    3   8   2018-03-03  6
2018    3   8   2018-03-04  7
2018    3   9   2018-03-05  1
2018    3   9   2018-03-06  2
2018    3   9   2018-03-07  3
2018    3   9   2018-03-08  4
2018    3   9   2018-03-09  5
2018    3   9   2018-03-10  6
2018    3   9   2018-03-11  7
2018    3   10  2018-03-12  1
2018    3   10  2018-03-13  2
2018    3   10  2018-03-14  3
2018    3   10  2018-03-15  4
2018    3   10  2018-03-16  5
2018    3   10  2018-03-17  6
2018    3   10  2018-03-18  7
2018    3   11  2018-03-19  1
2018    3   11  2018-03-20  2
2018    3   11  2018-03-21  3
2018    3   11  2018-03-22  4
2018    3   11  2018-03-23  5
2018    3   11  2018-03-24  6
2018    3   11  2018-03-25  7
2018    3   12  2018-03-26  1
2018    3   12  2018-03-27  2
2018    3   12  2018-03-28  3
2018    3   12  2018-03-29  4
2018    3   12  2018-03-30  5
2018    3   12  2018-03-31  6
2018    4   12  2018-04-01  7
2018    4   13  2018-04-02  1
2018    4   13  2018-04-03  2
2018    4   13  2018-04-04  3
2018    4   13  2018-04-05  4
2018    4   13  2018-04-06  5
2018    4   13  2018-04-07  6
2018    4   13  2018-04-08  7
2018    4   14  2018-04-09  1
2018    4   14  2018-04-10  2
2018    4   14  2018-04-11  3
2018    4   14  2018-04-12  4
2018    4   14  2018-04-13  5
2018    4   14  2018-04-14  6
2018    4   14  2018-04-15  7
2018    4   15  2018-04-16  1
2018    4   15  2018-04-17  2
2018    4   15  2018-04-18  3
2018    4   15  2018-04-19  4
2018    4   15  2018-04-20  5
2018    4   15  2018-04-21  6
2018    4   15  2018-04-22  7
2018    4   16  2018-04-23  1
2018    4   16  2018-04-24  2
2018    4   16  2018-04-25  3
2018    4   16  2018-04-26  4
2018    4   16  2018-04-27  5
2018    4   16  2018-04-28  6
2018    4   16  2018-04-29  7
2018    4   17  2018-04-30  1
2018    4   17  0   2
2018    4   17  0   3
2018    4   17  0   4
2018    4   17  0   5
2018    4   17  0   6
2018    5   16  0   7
2018    5   17  0   1
2018    5   17  2018-05-01  2
2018    5   17  2018-05-02  3
2018    5   17  2018-05-03  4
2018    5   17  2018-05-04  5
2018    5   17  2018-05-05  6
2018    5   17  2018-05-06  7
2018    5   18  2018-05-07  1
2018    5   18  2018-05-08  2
2018    5   18  2018-05-09  3
2018    5   18  2018-05-10  4
2018    5   18  2018-05-11  5
2018    5   18  2018-05-12  6
2018    5   18  2018-05-13  7
2018    5   19  2018-05-14  1
2018    5   19  2018-05-15  2
2018    5   19  2018-05-16  3
2018    5   19  2018-05-17  4
2018    5   19  2018-05-18  5
2018    5   19  2018-05-19  6
2018    5   19  2018-05-20  7
2018    5   20  2018-05-21  1
2018    5   20  2018-05-22  2
2018    5   20  2018-05-23  3
2018    5   20  2018-05-24  4
2018    5   20  2018-05-25  5
2018    5   20  2018-05-26  6
2018    5   20  2018-05-27  7
2018    5   21  2018-05-28  1
2018    5   21  2018-05-29  2
2018    5   21  2018-05-30  3
2018    5   21  2018-05-31  4
2018    5   21  0   5
2018    5   21  0   6
2018    6   20  0   7
2018    6   21  0   1
2018    6   21  0   2
2018    6   21  0   3
2018    6   21  0   4
2018    6   21  2018-06-01  5
2018    6   21  2018-06-02  6
2018    6   21  2018-06-03  7
2018    6   22  2018-06-04  1
2018    6   22  2018-06-05  2
2018    6   22  2018-06-06  3
2018    6   22  2018-06-07  4
2018    6   22  2018-06-08  5
2018    6   22  2018-06-09  6
2018    6   22  2018-06-10  7
2018    6   23  2018-06-11  1
2018    6   23  2018-06-12  2
2018    6   23  2018-06-13  3
2018    6   23  2018-06-14  4
2018    6   23  2018-06-15  5
2018    6   23  2018-06-16  6
2018    6   23  2018-06-17  7
2018    6   24  2018-06-18  1
2018    6   24  2018-06-19  2
2018    6   24  2018-06-20  3
2018    6   24  2018-06-21  4
2018    6   24  2018-06-22  5
2018    6   24  2018-06-23  6
2018    6   24  2018-06-24  7
2018    6   25  2018-06-25  1
2018    6   25  2018-06-26  2
2018    6   25  2018-06-27  3
2018    6   25  2018-06-28  4
2018    6   25  2018-06-29  5
2018    6   25  2018-06-30  6
2018    7   25  2018-07-01  7
2018    7   26  2018-07-02  1
2018    7   26  2018-07-03  2
2018    7   26  2018-07-04  3
2018    7   26  2018-07-05  4
2018    7   26  2018-07-06  5
2018    7   26  2018-07-07  6
2018    7   26  2018-07-08  7
2018    7   27  2018-07-09  1
2018    7   27  2018-07-10  2
2018    7   27  2018-07-11  3
2018    7   27  2018-07-12  4
2018    7   27  2018-07-13  5
2018    7   27  2018-07-14  6
2018    7   27  2018-07-15  7
2018    7   28  2018-07-16  1
2018    7   28  2018-07-17  2
2018    7   28  2018-07-18  3
2018    7   28  2018-07-19  4
2018    7   28  2018-07-20  5
2018    7   28  2018-07-21  6
2018    7   28  2018-07-22  7
2018    7   29  2018-07-23  1
2018    7   29  2018-07-24  2
2018    7   29  2018-07-25  3
2018    7   29  2018-07-26  4
2018    7   29  2018-07-27  5
2018    7   29  2018-07-28  6
2018    7   29  2018-07-29  7
2018    7   30  2018-07-30  1
2018    7   30  2018-07-31  2
2018    7   30  0   3
2018    7   30  0   4
2018    7   30  0   5
2018    7   30  0   6
2018    8   29  0   7
2018    8   30  0   1
2018    8   30  0   2
2018    8   30  2018-08-01  3
2018    8   30  2018-08-02  4
2018    8   30  2018-08-03  5
2018    8   30  2018-08-04  6
2018    8   30  2018-08-05  7
2018    8   31  2018-08-06  1
2018    8   31  2018-08-07  2
2018    8   31  2018-08-08  3
2018    8   31  2018-08-09  4
2018    8   31  2018-08-10  5
2018    8   31  2018-08-11  6
2018    8   31  2018-08-12  7
2018    8   32  2018-08-13  1
2018    8   32  2018-08-14  2
2018    8   32  2018-08-15  3
2018    8   32  2018-08-16  4
2018    8   32  2018-08-17  5
2018    8   32  2018-08-18  6
2018    8   32  2018-08-19  7
2018    8   33  2018-08-20  1
2018    8   33  2018-08-21  2
2018    8   33  2018-08-22  3
2018    8   33  2018-08-23  4
2018    8   33  2018-08-24  5
2018    8   33  2018-08-25  6
2018    8   33  2018-08-26  7
2018    8   34  2018-08-27  1
2018    8   34  2018-08-28  2
2018    8   34  2018-08-29  3
2018    8   34  2018-08-30  4
2018    8   34  2018-08-31  5
2018    8   34  0   6
2018    9   33  0   7
2018    9   34  0   1
2018    9   34  0   2
2018    9   34  0   3
2018    9   34  0   4
2018    9   34  0   5
2018    9   34  2018-09-01  6
2018    9   34  2018-09-02  7
2018    9   35  2018-09-03  1
2018    9   35  2018-09-04  2
2018    9   35  2018-09-05  3
2018    9   35  2018-09-06  4
2018    9   35  2018-09-07  5
2018    9   35  2018-09-08  6
2018    9   35  2018-09-09  7
2018    9   36  2018-09-10  1
2018    9   36  2018-09-11  2
2018    9   36  2018-09-12  3
2018    9   36  2018-09-13  4
2018    9   36  2018-09-14  5
2018    9   36  2018-09-15  6
2018    9   36  2018-09-16  7
2018    9   37  2018-09-17  1
2018    9   37  2018-09-18  2
2018    9   37  2018-09-19  3
2018    9   37  2018-09-20  4
2018    9   37  2018-09-21  5
2018    9   37  2018-09-22  6
2018    9   37  2018-09-23  7
2018    9   38  2018-09-24  1
2018    9   38  2018-09-25  2
2018    9   38  2018-09-26  3
2018    9   38  2018-09-27  4
2018    9   38  2018-09-28  5
2018    9   38  2018-09-29  6
2018    9   38  2018-09-30  7
2018    9   39  0   1
2018    9   39  0   2
2018    9   39  0   3
2018    9   39  0   4
2018    9   39  0   5
2018    9   39  0   6
2018    10  38  0   7
2018    10  39  2018-10-01  1
2018    10  39  2018-10-02  2
2018    10  39  2018-10-03  3
2018    10  39  2018-10-04  4
2018    10  39  2018-10-05  5
2018    10  39  2018-10-06  6
2018    10  39  2018-10-07  7
2018    10  40  2018-10-08  1
2018    10  40  2018-10-09  2
2018    10  40  2018-10-10  3
2018    10  40  2018-10-11  4
2018    10  40  2018-10-12  5
2018    10  40  2018-10-13  6
2018    10  40  2018-10-14  7
2018    10  41  2018-10-15  1
2018    10  41  2018-10-16  2
2018    10  41  2018-10-17  3
2018    10  41  2018-10-18  4
2018    10  41  2018-10-19  5
2018    10  41  2018-10-20  6
2018    10  41  2018-10-21  7
2018    10  42  2018-10-22  1
2018    10  42  2018-10-23  2
2018    10  42  2018-10-24  3
2018    10  42  2018-10-25  4
2018    10  42  2018-10-26  5
2018    10  42  2018-10-27  6
2018    10  42  2018-10-28  7
2018    10  43  2018-10-29  1
2018    10  43  2018-10-30  2
2018    10  43  2018-10-31  3
2018    10  43  0   4
2018    10  43  0   5
2018    10  43  0   6
2018    11  42  0   7
2018    11  43  0   1
2018    11  43  0   2
2018    11  43  0   3
2018    11  43  2018-11-01  4
2018    11  43  2018-11-02  5
2018    11  43  2018-11-03  6
2018    11  43  2018-11-04  7
2018    11  44  2018-11-05  1
2018    11  44  2018-11-06  2
2018    11  44  2018-11-07  3
2018    11  44  2018-11-08  4
2018    11  44  2018-11-09  5
2018    11  44  2018-11-10  6
2018    11  44  2018-11-11  7
2018    11  45  2018-11-12  1
2018    11  45  2018-11-13  2
2018    11  45  2018-11-14  3
2018    11  45  2018-11-15  4
2018    11  45  2018-11-16  5
2018    11  45  2018-11-17  6
2018    11  45  2018-11-18  7
2018    11  46  2018-11-19  1
2018    11  46  2018-11-20  2
2018    11  46  2018-11-21  3
2018    11  46  2018-11-22  4
2018    11  46  2018-11-23  5
2018    11  46  2018-11-24  6
2018    11  46  2018-11-25  7
2018    11  47  2018-11-26  1
2018    11  47  2018-11-27  2
2018    11  47  2018-11-28  3
2018    11  47  2018-11-29  4
2018    11  47  2018-11-30  5
2018    11  47  0   6
2018    12  46  0   7
2018    12  47  0   1
2018    12  47  0   2
2018    12  47  0   3
2018    12  47  0   4
2018    12  47  0   5
2018    12  47  2018-12-01  6
2018    12  47  2018-12-02  7
2018    12  48  2018-12-03  1
2018    12  48  2018-12-04  2
2018    12  48  2018-12-05  3
2018    12  48  2018-12-06  4
2018    12  48  2018-12-07  5
2018    12  48  2018-12-08  6
2018    12  48  2018-12-09  7
2018    12  49  2018-12-10  1
2018    12  49  2018-12-11  2
2018    12  49  2018-12-12  3
2018    12  49  2018-12-13  4
2018    12  49  2018-12-14  5
2018    12  49  2018-12-15  6
2018    12  49  2018-12-16  7
2018    12  50  2018-12-17  1
2018    12  50  2018-12-18  2
2018    12  50  2018-12-19  3
2018    12  50  2018-12-20  4
2018    12  50  2018-12-21  5
2018    12  50  2018-12-22  6
2018    12  50  2018-12-23  7
2018    12  51  2018-12-24  1
2018    12  51  2018-12-25  2
2018    12  51  2018-12-26  3
2018    12  51  2018-12-27  4
2018    12  51  2018-12-28  5
2018    12  51  2018-12-29  6
2018    12  51  2018-12-30  7
2018    12  52  2018-12-31  1
2018    12  52  0   2
2018    12  52  0   3
2018    12  52  0   4
2018    12  52  0   5
2018    12  52  0   6
```

-- supporting SQL Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `date_48361641` (
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    truncate date_48361641 ;

insert into date_48361641 ( `date` )
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2016-01-01' and '2018-12-31' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to solve your query. I assume that your minimal date is over 1900-01-01. If not put any other date that is under than your minimal date and is monday
Also there may be better solution with recursive cte

```
with cte as (
    select cast(a as datetime) date, b week_day from (values ('20180201',4)
    ,('20180202',5)
    ,('20180203',6)
    ,('20180204',7)
    ,('20180205',1)
    ,('20180206',2)
    ,('20180207',3)
    ,('20180226',1)
    ,('20180227',2)
    ,('20180228',3) 

    ,('20181231',1)
    ,('20190101',2)
    ,('20190102',3)
    ,('20190103',4)
    ,('20190104',5)
    ) t(a,b)
)
select
    iif((rn = 1 and charindex(k, st) > 0) or k is null, convert(varchar(10), date, 120), '0')
    , isnull(k, week_day)
from (
    select
        date, week_day, ww
        , concat(max(iif(week_day = 1, 1, null)) over (partition by ww)
        , max(iif(week_day = 2, 2, null)) over (partition by ww)
        , max(iif(week_day = 3, 3, null)) over (partition by ww)
        , max(iif(week_day = 4, 4, null)) over (partition by ww)
        , max(iif(week_day = 5, 5, null)) over (partition by ww)
        , max(iif(week_day = 6, 6, null)) over (partition by ww)
        , max(iif(week_day = 7, 7, null)) over (partition by ww)) st
        , row_number() over (partition by ww order by week_day) rn
    from
        cte
        cross apply (select datediff(dd, cast('19000101' as datetime), date) / 7 ww) q
) t
left join (values ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7')) z(k) 
on 
    rn = 1 
    and (charindex(k, st) = 0 or iif(rn = 1, week_day, 0) = k)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work

```
with allDates as (
see link below to finish this part
)

select DateFieldFromYourTable
, isnull(WeekDay, 0) DayOfWeek
from allDates left join YourTable on allDates.Something = DateFieldFromYourTable
```

Read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a05deb57-a12b-40e6-8932-d5fe543c21c6/generating-a-list-of-sequential-dates?forum=transactsql) to get the code for your subquery.

Comment: I'm an experienced developer and even I can't fathom how this would work!

Comment: The condition is about `week_day` not `Date`